# How to search data in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
   String name = bundle.getString("name");

   mValueView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

   mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReferenceFromUrl("https://mymap-3fd93.firebaseio.com/Users");

   com.google.firebase.database.Query query = mRef.child("Users").orderByChild("title").equalTo(name);

   query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
       @Override
       public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
           //Map<String,Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
           //String Title = (String) map.get("title");
           String Title = dataSnapshot.child("title").getValue().toString();
           mValueView.setText(Title);

       }

       @Override
       public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

       }
   });
```

I want to show object title is same name value.

This is the Firebase database:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to search title value only one time, without listening for updates, you can simply use :

```
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
                    new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    }});
```

Then if you get a reference to 'Users' you can do some logic with iteration, for example :

```
for (DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
    String title = (String) singleSnapshot.child("title").getValue();
                        //do your logic
                    }
```

Comment: how to use singleSnapshot?

Comment: String title = (String) singleSnapshot.child("title");

Comment: I try this code but it error. Have .getValue() next child("title")?

Comment: what do you need to do after you have got your object?

Comment: when i got it. I want to check value is equal name(EX.name = Chatuchak) and show all child in firebase on textview

Comment: your desired singleSnapshot has as key 'two' and contains all attributes as title and children you put in it. Get attributes as i've explained before, and get children as an HashMap<Type, Type>. For example : (HashMap<String, String>) singleSnapshot.child("child0").getValue(); 
You have to serialize the entire hierarchy. If you want to know if a child exists, use singleSnapshot.hasChild("name"); 
Please vote my answer if it's useful

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems in your code:

1. you're specifying the child node `Users` twice
2. a query results a list of results, which your `onDataChange` doesn't handle

#### specifying the child node `Users` twice

```
mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
         .getReferenceFromUrl("https://mymap-3fd93.firebaseio.com/Users");
                                                               // ^^^^^ 

Query query = mRef.child("Users").orderByChild("title").equalTo(name);
                       // ^^^^^
```

Easily fixed:

```
mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
         .getReferenceFromUrl("https://mymap-3fd93.firebaseio.com/");

Query query = mRef.child("Users").orderByChild("title").equalTo(name);
```

I'm not sure why you use `getReferenceFromUrl()` to begin with. For most applications, this accomplishes the same is simpler:

```
mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

#### a query results a list of results

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

```
   query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
       @Override
       public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
           for (DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
               System.out.println(snapshot.getKey());
               System.out.println(snapshot.child("title").getValue(String.class));
           }
       }

       @Override
       public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
           throw databaseError.toException();
       }
   });
```