# Search in firebase database for android?

Tags: android, firebase, search, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

project name > users > user1key > name , latitude , longitude

> user2key > name , latitude , longitude

This is the tree in database. I want a query to search the user using its name. and get its details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
ref.orderByChild("name").equalTo("Yash Mehta").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
      System.out.println(userSnapshot.getKey());
      System.out.println(userSnapshot.child("Name").getValue(String.class));
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    throw databaseError.toException();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**you are looking for something like the following.**

> *This is example search name*

```
refDatabase.child("users").orderByChild("user2key").orderByChild("name").equalTo("search here word").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
    new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //data will be available on dataSnapshot.getValue();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.w(TAG, "getUser:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        }
});
```

**If it does not meet the requirements try these**

> [How to search for a value in firebase Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34537369/how-to-search-for-a-value-in-firebase-android)
>
> [How to search data in Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41951877/how-to-search-data-in-firebase)
>
> [How to Search for data in Firebase Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37928163/how-to-search-for-data-in-firebase-android)